# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext

Tags: java, serialization, netty, apache-storm

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext     at
>   org.apache.storm.serialization.SerializableSerializer.write(SerializableSerializer.java:41)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245]   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
>   ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.write(MapSerializer.java:113)
>   ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.write(MapSerializer.java:39)
>   ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
>   ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100)
>   ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
>   ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:534)
>   ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]   at
>   org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoValuesSerializer.serializeInto(KryoValuesSerializer.java:44)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245]   at
>   org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoTupleSerializer.serialize(KryoTupleSerializer.java:44)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245]   at
>   org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$mk_transfer_fn$transfer_fn__6723.invoke(worker.clj:192)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245]   at
>   org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$start_batch_transfer__GT_worker_handler_BANG_$fn__6411.invoke(executor.clj:313)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245]   at
>   org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__6005.onEvent(disruptor.clj:40)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245]   at
>   org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:451)
>   ~[storm-core-1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245.jar:1.0.1.2.5.0.0-1245]   ... 6 more

I use a storm local mode is no problem, but on the cluster will be reported to the fault.

this is my code:

```
public class NettySpout extends BaseRichSpout {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/**
 * colloctor for spout
 */
private SpoutOutputCollector collector;

@Override
public void open(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, SpoutOutputCollector spoutOutputCollector) {
    collector=spoutOutputCollector;
    StormServer stormServer=new StormServer();
    stormServer.run();
}

@Override
public void nextTuple() {
    Values tuple;
    try {
        while ((tuple = ServerHandler.queue.take()) != null) {
            collector.emit(tuple);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
    outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("value","channl"));
}


public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter{

private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ServerHandler.class);
public static LinkedBlockingQueue<Values> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Values>();
public static Map<String,ChannelHandlerContext> ctxes;

public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)  throws Exception {
    JSONObject message = (JSONObject) msg;
    queue.put(new Values(new StreamData(message.toString().getBytes()), new HashMap<>(ctxes)));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not much knowledge about storm itself but it seems like you try to serialise ChannelHandlerContext (as its stored in your Map) which is not Serializable.

Comment: You are right ,the ChannelHandlerContext Cannot be serialized,maybe this way is wrong ,I should try other way.Thank you for your answer.